"WebDriverIO and Appium Service Fails with Error 'Appium Exited Before Timeout'"
enter image description here
enter image description here
I am encountering an issue while running WebDriverIO tests with Appium. The service fails during the 'onPrepare' hook, and Appium exits before the timeout.
`2024-08-06T11:01:46.324Z DEBUG @wdio/utils:initializeServices: initialize service "appium" as NPM package
2024-08-06T11:01:46.484Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onPrepare hook
2024-08-06T11:01:46.544Z INFO @wdio/appium-service: Will spawn Appium process: cmd /c node C:\Users\akrivia\webdriverio-appium-v8\node_modules\appium\index.js --base-path /
2024-08-06T11:01:54.848Z ERROR @wdio/appium-service: WARN
2024-08-06T11:01:54.850Z ERROR @wdio/cli:utils: A service failed in the 'onPrepare' hook
Error: WARN
at Socket. (file:///C:/Users/akrivia/webdriverio-appium-v8/node_modules/@wdio/appium-service/build/launcher.js:174:28)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:634:26)
at Socket.emit (node:events:519:28)
at Socket.emit (node:domain:488:12)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:559:12)
at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:510:3)
at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:390:5)
at Pipe.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:191:23)
Continue...
2024-08-06T11:01:54.851Z DEBUG @wdio/cli:utils: Finished to run "onPrepare" hook in 8366ms
2024-08-06T11:01:54.856Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerStart hook
2024-08-06T11:01:54.856Z DEBUG @wdio/cli:utils: Finished to run "onWorkerStart" hook in 0ms
2024-08-06T11:01:54.858Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Start worker 0-0 with arg:
2024-08-06T11:01:54.878Z DEBUG @wdio/local-runner: Send command run to worker with cid "0-0"
2024-08-06T11:01:55.027Z ERROR @wdio/appium-service: Appium exited before timeout (exit code: 1)
WARN
[0-0] Error: "ts-node/esm/transpile-only 'resolve'" did not call the next hook in its chain and did not explicitly signal a short circuit. If this is intentional, include shortCircuit: true in the hook's return.
[0-0]     at Hooks.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:312:13)
[0-0]     at MessagePort.handleMessage (node:internal/modules/esm/worker:196:18)
2024-08-06T11:01:56.711Z DEBUG @wdio/local-runner: Runner 0-0 finished with exit code 1
[0-0] FAILED
2024-08-06T11:01:56.713Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerEnd hook
2024-08-06T11:01:56.714Z DEBUG @wdio/cli:utils: Finished to run "onWorkerEnd" hook in 0ms
2024-08-06T11:01:56.714Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onComplete hook
2024-08-06T11:01:56.715Z DEBUG @wdio/cli:utils: Finished to run "onComplete" hook in 0ms

Please put some line breaks in this. It's impossible to read in its current form.
Just looking at the error message it sounds like what you're doing caused an exception of some kind. Can you see the Apium log?
